# synchronization: producer/consumer not locking the count

Tags: algorithm, synchronization

The following code is taken from Wikipedia:

```
semaphore mutex = 1;
semaphore fillCount = 0;
semaphore emptyCount = BUFFER_SIZE;

procedure producer() {
    while (true) {
        item = produceItem();
        down(emptyCount);
            down(mutex);
                putItemIntoBuffer(item);
            up(mutex);
        up(fillCount);
    }
}

procedure consumer() {
    while (true) {
        down(fillCount);
            down(mutex);
                item = removeItemFromBuffer();
            up(mutex);
        up(emptyCount);
        consumeItem(item);
    }
}
```

What I'm confused is why the down/up(fillCount) in consumer and producers are outside of mutex. Doesn't that mean they're exposed to being modified by more than 1 threads at the same time?

Comment: Semaphore operations are atomic by definition.  (That is, semaphores themselves are a synchronization mechanism, not entirely unlike mutexes.)

Comment: Please add wikipedia link to question for clarity.